# Optimise particles.js background to avoid high CPU usage

Tags: javascript, particles, particles.js

I'm working on a project where I want to fill two div elements with particles using particle.js. As expected, doing it results in high CPU usage causing all sorts of troubles – the site becomes laggy, other JS libraries (typing text) become slow, and obviously the fan turns on after a few seconds.

Example: https://codepen.io/sharkmountain/pen/bGNpdMe

```
// ParticlesJS Config.
particlesJS("particles-js", {
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 2000,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 100
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#ffffff"
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": "circle",
      "stroke": {
        "width": 0,
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
    },
    "opacity": {
      "value": 0.5,
      "random": false,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 1,
        "opacity_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 3,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 40,
        "size_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": false
    },
    "move": {
      "enable": true,
      "speed": 6,
      "direction": "none",
      "random": false,
      "straight": false,
      "out_mode": "out",
      "bounce": false,
      "attract": {
        "enable": false,
        "rotateX": 600,
        "rotateY": 1200
      }
    }
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "grab"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "push"
      },
      "resize": true
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 140,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 200,
        "duration": 0.4
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 4
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "retina_detect": true
});
```

I've tried setting the FTP frame limiter as [suggested here](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/issues/283) but that didn't make a difference.

I honestly don't expect a solution but curious if anyone does have an idea how to make it work without causing performance troubles.

Answer (score 3):

You really only have 3 options that I can see

1. Limit the FPS. 30 is good enough for a plain old animation like this.
2. Decrease the number and/or size of the particles (this will decrease fillrate)
3. Eliminate transparency (this will reduce overdraw)

Comment: Thanks @gburton – I've tried 1 and 2 but I'll also throw your third suggestion in the mix and see if that makes a difference. Thanks for your quick answer.